# contenteditable causing jqueryui sortable to lag while dragging. Temporarily remove contenteditable while dragging?

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

This time i took some time to analyse before I would ask.

**PROBLEM:**

I have several divs which contain several children with 'contenteditable="true"'.

If I add lots of text into every 'contenteditable="true"' div and then start dragging it, my performance plummets.

So I change the 'contenteditable="true"' divs into input fields.

Performance continues to go down the same way.

***While on the site, i use dev tools to remove the contenteditable from all children and the performance is perfect while dragging.***

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION:**

Temporarily remove the attribute "contenteditable" or set it to "false" when drag starts and add reverse after stop:
I just dunno how exactly to do it, would it be similar tho what I've done with the placeholder height when start ?

would need sometimeng that does something like this: 
`$(this).find('.twoxboximage,twoxboxheader,twoxboxtext').remove(attr("contenteditable"));`

But I dunno the exact syntax, this is my HTML and the sortable JS.

```js
$('#description_list').sortable({
cancel:'.smallbox',
axis:'y',
tolerance: 'pointer',
placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
 
start: function(e, ui){
 ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
 //code that removes every contentneditable="true" from specific children from dragged div
},
stop: function(){
 copycontent();
 //code that adds every contentneditable="true" from specific children from dragged div
}
});
  
$('#description_list').sortable({
  connectWith: 'smallbox-wrapper'
});
```

```html
<div id="description_list" class="bigbox">
 <div class="smallbox-wrapper twoxboxicon" id="row1">
 <div class="widewrapper">
  <input type="button" class="swapbutton" value="⇔"><input type="button" class="deletebutton " value="X" title="Löschen" onclick="delete_row('row2')">
 </div>
 <div class="smallbox twob1">
  <div id="title" class="smallbox twoxboximage" contenteditable="true" placeholder="image.."></div>
  <div id="title" class="smallbox twoxboxheader" contenteditable="true" placeholder="header.."></div>
  <div id="title" class="smallbox twoxboxtext" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Text.."></div>
 </div>
 <div class="smallbox twob2">
  <div id="title" class="smallbox twoxboximage" contenteditable="true" placeholder="image.."></div>
  <div id="title" class="smallbox twoxboxheader" contenteditable="true" placeholder="header.."></div>
  <div id="title" class="smallbox twoxboxtext" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Text.."></div>
 </div>
 <div class="up"></div>
 <div class="down"></div>
 </div>
 
 
 <div class="smallbox-wrapper twoxboxicon" id="row2">
 <div class="widewrapper">
  <input type="button" class="swapbutton" value="⇔"><input type="button" class="deletebutton " value="X" title="Löschen" onclick="delete_row('row2')">
 </div>
 <div class="smallbox twob1">
  <div id="title" class="smallbox twoxboximage" contenteditable="true" placeholder="image.."></div>
  <div id="title" class="smallbox twoxboxheader" contenteditable="true" placeholder="header.."></div>
  <div id="title" class="smallbox twoxboxtext" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Text.."></div>
 </div>
 <div class="smallbox twob2">
  <div id="title" class="smallbox twoxboximage" contenteditable="true" placeholder="image.."></div>
  <div id="title" class="smallbox twoxboxheader" contenteditable="true" placeholder="header.."></div>
  <div id="title" class="smallbox twoxboxtext" contenteditable="true" placeholder="Text.."></div>
 </div>
 <div class="up"></div>
 <div class="down"></div>
 </div>
 
 ... and so on
</div>
```

Any Ideas ?

Much appreciated and lots of love

Gram

**--EDIT 1--**

Okay so i got this KINDA working but i have two issues:

```
     $('#description_list').sortable({
        cancel:'.smallbox',
        axis:'y',
        tolerance: 'pointer',
        placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
        start: function(e, ui){
            ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
            ui.item.find(".twoxboxheader, .twoxboximage, .twoxboxtext").each(function(){
                $(this).prop('contenteditable', false);
            });
        },
        stop: function(){
            copycontent();
            ui.item.find(".twoxboxheader, .twoxboximage, .twoxboxtext").each(function(){
                $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
            });
        }
});

$('#description_list').sortable({
    connectWith: 'smallbox-wrapper'
});
```

It doesnt apply the contentneditable back to the element, I dunno why.

Also, it would be better to apply contenteditable='false' to every '.smallbox-wrapper' inside the '#description_list' since the performance also gets affected if i drag above an item which has contenteditable 'true'.

I will try to solve this and post the answer here, everyone is welcome to help out :D

sincerely

Gram

**--EDIT 2--**

OK forgot the ui for the stop: function

```
stop: function(e, ui){}
```

Will try to apply this routine to every child inside '#description_list' and post answer here.

sincerely

Gram

Answer (score 0):

Okay got it !

First i Tried the over: and out: events but they didnt quite work so i switched over to simply find every smallbox and set contentneditable to false on start: and to true on stop:

here's the code, hope it helps others.

```js
  $('#description_list').sortable({
   cancel:'.smallbox',
   axis:'y',
   tolerance: 'pointer',
   placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
   //when starting to drag
   start: function(e, ui){
    ui.placeholder.height(ui.item.height());
    $('.smallbox').each(function(){
    
     //removing contentneditable from every affected div to improve performance drastically
     if ($(this).is('.twoxboxheader, .twoxboximage, .twoxboxtext')) {
     $(this).prop('contenteditable', false);
     };

    });
   },
   //when stopping to drag
   stop: function(e, ui){
    $('.smallbox').each(function(){
    
     //adding contentneditable to every affected div 
     if ($(this).is('.twoxboxheader, .twoxboximage, .twoxboxtext')) {
     $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
     };

    });
    copycontent();
   }
 });
  
 $('#description_list').sortable({
  connectWith: 'smallbox-wrapper'
 });
```

Cheers.

Gram

Comment: I will use the .smallbox class for other, non-editable divs so i wen't with the class list, otherwise a simple

$('.smallbox').each(function(){
    
 $(this).prop('contenteditable', false);

}); Would be enough and probably save some performance